# Should I use Automator or another program for repetitious tasks?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, automator, automation

I have 100s of images to save out in a different format for a project that I am working on. And the problem is I have to do them one at a time, so I am wondering if there is some way to record the actions of me saving one of them out and then having the program repeat it by looking in a specific directory and doing it with all of the images. I am not sure how else to explain what I am trying to do, but I just need some way to make the program that I am using automate the saving task for each image. P.S I don't know if it helps but the program that I am using is called (Texture Packer)

Comment: The answer is clearly yes. Use automation!

Comment: How can I use automator with a program like texture packer? From what I can see automator only uses apps that come with OS X.

Comment: I recommend Photoshop if you have it. Just record the actions, and then batch them all.

Comment: @bassplayer7 I would use photoshop but the format that I need to save them in is (.pvr) format and texture packer is the only one that does that.

Comment: Aah - so the problem is you aren't sure what tools can automate a program that doesn't include a dictionary of actions that feeds directly into Automator...

Comment: @bmike that is precisely what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the TexturePacker program includes the ability to process images from the command-line, which you could then batch process with a script. You'll first want to install the utility by clicking **Install Command Line Tool** under the **TexturePacker** menu in the app.

Then I'd suggest having a look at the [documentation](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/documentation), which includes the command-line parameters for most of the options in the app. Have a look at that, and see if you can get  the actions you need on the command-line. If you need help turning those into a batch processing script, I'd suggest coming back and amending your question with the specifics.

Comment: I installed the command line tool and found on the texturePacker blog that this is how you batch convert images. `find <directoryname> -name \*.png | sed 's/\.png//g' | \
    xargs -I % -n 1 TexturePacker %.png \
        --sheet %.pvr.ccz \
        --data dummy.plist \
        --algorithm Basic \
        --allow-free-size \
        --no-trim \
        --opt RGBA4444 \
        --dither-fs `But I keep getting this output in the terminal. (find: *.png: No such file or directory)

Comment: @Stephen I answered this in the other question you posted.